# Query issue in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I am having some issues with finding documents with a today's date function through python.

I use the following function:

```
datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

which gives the following value: `2017-05-21`

However, the values in my documents (mongo) have double strings attached around it like the following: `"2017-05-21"`

So literally filling in the above string ("2017-05-21") exactly in my pymongo query works like a charm. However, I need the dynamicness of the datetime function, but unfortunately, that doesn't match with the double quoted date strings which I need for the query.

Does anyone know any workaround? I have already tried a replace function etc. It either creates double quotes within the single quotes or doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your MongoDB documents were inserted incorrectly, using text for date fields instead of BSON datetimes.

PyMongo automatically converts between Python datetimes and BSON datetimes, so you can insert a document that contains a BSON datetime like this:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
collection.insert_one({'myDate': dt})
```

Prove that date comparisons work now like so:

```
# There is a document with myDate in the past, now.
print(collection.find_one({'myDate': {'$lt': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}}))
# No document with myDate in the future.
print(collection.find_one({'myDate': {'$gt': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}}))
```

Comment: Thanks A. Jesse, I haven't tried your solution yet, but can already sense that it will work. Many thanks!!